# How to call SSRS Report on asp.net Framework 2.0

Tags: reporting-services, .net-2.0, reportviewer, scriptmanager

I am looking for some tutorial that can guide me as to how can I call an `SSRS` report in my project. All the tutorials/articles I have come across use `ScriptManager` and `ReportViewer` controls from the `asp.net` toolbox but these controls aren't available in framework 2.0. Any solution?

Comment: did you try to add the Reportviewer in your toolBox using this :right-click the Toolbox and select Choose Items, then in the tab of Components .Net Framework search report viewer and add the Component

Comment: Yes I did and I got the following error
`failed to create designer microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer version 10.0.0.0`